# Swift: Very slow Horizontal scroll of UICollection

Tags: ios, swift, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to implement a horizontal scroll on a collection view, but I face a very weird problem. On any iPhone simulator **other** **than** iPhone X, when scrolling from the first cell to the second cell, the animation is very slow. After that, everything work just fine.

You can see the issue by following link below:

[The problem](https://codehousefive.com/slow-scroll.gif)

The problem starts when I add the following code in viewDidLoad to make cells snap:

```
self.collectionView?.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

Edit:

Below is the code i am using to control swiping the way i want to (as shown in the video):

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and why iPhone X is working fine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when I add the following code in viewDidLoad to make cells snap" Not sure what you mean by that. If the idea is to make cells snap to the center (paging), that's not how to do it.

Comment: @matt check my edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if what you want to do is make a "paging" collection view where the cell always stops in the center when the user scrolls, that's not how to do it. The correct way is to subclass the layout and implement `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:`.

Comment: Two questions: a) How is this different than scrollViewWillEndDragging when it comes to what i want to achieve? b) say that I implement the same scrolling effect with targetContentOffset by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout. How do I make cell snap without using collectionView?.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast? Thanks

Comment: “How is this different than scrollViewWillEndDragging” You do _both_. But in neither case is it about the deceleration rate.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of implementing both? How do I recreate the "snap" effect if not by using decelerationRate?

Comment: Google “carousel” please.